# Azure Databricks Structured Streaming with ForeachWriter

Tags: azure, spark-streaming

I'm trying to invoke an REST API by passing a value directly from structured  streams .  I'm trying to implement that in following manner. I'm not expecting any response out of this REST API call., but I need to ensure each calls made to end point were successful. How can I ensure this?. Currently, all calls made weren't successful and am not able to trace it. any suggestions.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter
val writer = new ForeachWriter[String] {
  override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long) = true
  override def process(value: String) = {
     import sys.process._
     val command = """curl -d '{"Id":"""+ value + """}'  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X POST http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/xxx/xxxxx/xxxx"""
     Seq("/bin/bash","-c",command).!!
  }
  override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable) = {}
}

val results = output.map(r => r.getString(0))

results.writeStream
  .queryName("rest-api-processor")
  .foreach(writer)
  .start
  .awaitTermination
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executed command from Bash with in Spark without `.!!`, as mentioned. Alternatively, we can print statement too.

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter
val writer = new ForeachWriter[Row] {
  override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long) = true
  override def process(value: Row) = {
     import sys.process._
     val command = """curl -d '{"Id":"""+ value + """}'  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X POST http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/xxx/xxxxx/xxxx"""
     Seq("/bin/bash","-c",command)
  }
  override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable) = {}
}
```